# Error in PHP script

Tags: php, xampp

I wrote a PHP script. When i try to use it throws an error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/login2.php on line 11

line 11- $query = “SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ‘$un’ AND password = ‘$pw’”;
```

I am running Apache and MySQL using XAMPP on my mac.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code I am using in the script

```
< ?php

$un=$_POST['username'];

$pw=$_POST['password'];

//connect to the db

$user = ‘su’;

$pswd = ‘passwd’;

$db = ‘people’;

$conn = mysql_connect(‘localhost’, $user, $pswd);

mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

//run the query to search for the username and password the match

$query = “SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ‘$un’ AND password = ‘$pw’”;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(“Unable to verify user because : ” . mysql_error());

//this is where the actual verification happens

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)

echo 1; // for correct login response

else

echo 0; // for incorrect login response

?>
```

Comment: you should look into `sql injections`

Comment: or mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: or prepared statements and pdo.

Comment: @BookOfZeus: That and password hashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using curly quotes. You MUST use straight quotes `"`.

Answer (score 3):

What editor are you using to enter your code? You have Unicode quotation marks `“ ”` and `‘ ’` which are normally only entered using a word processor. PHP will not recognize these quotes, and you must use `" "` and `' '` instead, which is what you will get from any programmer's editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use either single or double quotes for your strings - looks like you are using the backtick operator;